# Integer becomes decimal in merged dataframe using python pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two csv file and all the numeric fields are int, no decimal.
When I use pandas merge function to join two dataframe, I found the int fields in one dataframe all became decimal, why that happens?

[image: int becomes decimal]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each column of a DataFrame has a dtype. The dtype controls what kinds of values can be contained in that column. Columns with integer dtypes, unsurprisingly, can contain only integers. Columns with floating point dtypes contain only floats -- and `NaN` is a float:

```
In [191]: isinstance(np.nan, float)
Out[191]: True
```

So even though `age` and `score` are integer-valued columns, since the merged `age_y` and `score_y` columns contain `NaN`, the dtype must be upgraded to a floating point dtype to accommodate the `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks unutbu! When I fillna NAN with -99, all the values came back to int.